# Allow customer to set up his BrainTree Account in My Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I am working on this app where i have users and the user can set up payment gateway of his choice from which he wants his (user's) customers to pay while checking out. I have got to implement BrainTree and have no idea how to do it.

I have to ask the user to enter his public key, private key and his merchant id in my app and that would set up his payment gateway. I'm not sure i'm very clear and i'm also clueless as to search what exactly and with what to start.

Please guide me in the right direction. Also do comment if its not clear. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

P.S: Just so that this is clear. My user has his customers and he will enter his braintree account details so that braintree is his payment gateway.

Comment: do you want to know that how you can configure braintree merchant account with rails application?

Comment: i think its more like setting up braintree accounts during run time. The app asks for the credentials to the user and once the credentials match, his account sets up for payments.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Braintree's [Braintree Auth](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-auth/overview) product.